# Change the button name when click on that button

Tags: android, button

Can anyone tell me how can i change the random button name when 
click on that button.

Comment: btn.setText("foo") in onclick ,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the name to be ***random*** or you want a ***particular*** name when you click that button?

If you want a **random** name, then use the following code:

```
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClicklistener(){
@Override
public void OnClick(View v)
{
   ((Button)v).setText(q);

}
});
```

Here `q` is nothing but the string which you will be obtained by following answer
[Show random string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717614/show-random-string)

And for **particular** name, you can follow the other answers.

Comment: yes, thanks you about solution,and I will try it

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View v)
   {
        button2.setText("New Text");
   }

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't really help much with that little information, but here is a quite generic way to achieve what you seem to want:

```
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
yourButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        ((Button) v).setText("new text");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what I mean is if the button on click it will change the button text itself

Comment: @adig I'm not quite sure I get what you mean. This code does change the text of the button itself.

Comment: yes, it did change. but I mean the show more than one text at random if the button is clicked